# how can i generate noisy datasets with different shape of clusters in python?

Tags: python, data-mining

i need to generate a noisy dataset, with different shape of clusters in python, something like the picture in below. can please help me?  thanks.

[noisy dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJMHF.png)

Comment: Have a look here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html it shows some examples of how to create clustering examples

Comment: Scikit-learn has some convenient functions for this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/sample_generators.html#sample-generators